# What is the best free web app to send invoices to client?

Tags: webapp-rec

I need simple and free invoice service and money transaction like PayPal should not be included with that.

I just want to send invoice.

Comment: See [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2298/1512) also.

Answer (score 1):

[Freshbooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/) is free up to 3 clients.  I haven't tried it myself, but comes highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Note: All the following are invoices via email. You can print the invoice and sent it by mail should you wish.

- [PayPal](http://www.paypal.com) - free, simple invoices (Tried them, though, and the invoicing part wasn't powerful enough for me. So I use Freshbooks - below - instead.)
- [Freshbooks](http://www.freshbooks.com) - Free invoices for up to 3 clients. Does offer invoice-by-mail for small fee.
- [WaveAccounting](http://www.waveaccounting.com) - Accounting for your business + invoicing
- [Invoicera](http://www.invoicera.com) - Free for a certain 3 clients.
- [BillingBoss](http://www.billingboss.com) - Free.
- [SnapBill](http://www.snapbill.com) - 5 clients & 15 invoices/month free.

Comment: Can I send invoice in mail to my client using Freshbooks?

Comment: Yes, you can. It does cost a little to do so (They give you like one for free, IIRC), but if you need it by mail, it's not a bad price. I'll look it up next time I'm in freshbooks (which will be tonight).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send invoices, accept money and to own you data, you have to look at [MyClientBase](http://myclientbase.com) which is a good choice and the new version can accept money using PayPal.

But if you don’t care about owning your data you can check [Wave Accounting](http://waveaccounting.com), which has a personal and business accounting for the same account, but I’m not so sure if you can accept money using it.